# How to disable getting column descriptions along with a query result? (mysql2/promise)

Tags: node.js, mysql2

I'm using the `mysql2/promise` package. And here's what I'm doing:

```
  const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
  const dbConnection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: environment.dbUrl,
    port: '3306',
    user: environment.dbUser,
    password: environment.dbPassword,
    database: environment.db,
  });
  return (dbConnection);

  const verifications = await dbConnection.execute('SELECT * FROM verifications WHERE code = ?', [code]);
  console.log('verifications', verifications);
```

But the query result is containing a bunch of column descriptions that I don't need. How shall I get rid of them?

```
[ [],
  [ { catalog: 'def',
      schema: 'testdb',
      name: 'id',
      orgName: 'id',
      table: 'verifications',
      orgTable: 'verifications',
      characterSet: 63,
      columnLength: 11,
      columnType: 3,
      flags: 16899,
      decimals: 0 },
    { catalog: 'def',
      schema: 'testdb',
      name: 'code',
      orgName: 'code',
      table: 'verifications',
      orgTable: 'verifications',
      characterSet: 63,
      columnLength: 11,
      columnType: 3,
      flags: 4097,
      decimals: 0 },
    { catalog: 'def',
      schema: 'testdb',
      name: 'createdAt',
      orgName: 'createdAt',
      table: 'verifications',
      orgTable: 'verifications',
      characterSet: 63,
      columnLength: 19,
      columnType: 7,
      flags: 1152,
      decimals: 0 } ] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do `const [rows, fields]` to get the relevant info

```
  const [rows, fields] = await dbConnection.execute('SELECT * FROM verifications WHERE code = ?', [code]);
```